# IIS 7 - How can I add an IPv6 address to the IIS IP restrictions list?

Tags: iis-7, ipv6

We have a load of IPv4 addresses restricting access to an API here. The problem is, I need to allow the local server to connect to itself for testing and diag, but even though I added the local IPv4 range to the allow list, it doesn't work.

My theory is that because IPv6 is configured locally, it uses this protocol in the connection (to itself) and so its still blocked.

How can I add an IPv6 address to the IIS IP restrictions list?

Comment: I have a workaround: use http://{local_ip} instead of the name and this forces IPv4 and my IPv4 allow rule passes!

Comment: Really no one knows how to add IPv6 addresses??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does this answer your question?
http://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2008/05/03/using-ipv6-with-iis7.aspx

> ... The inetmgr UI has an artificial restriction for allowing only
>   IPv4 addresses and this is mostly because of test constraints on our
>   part. However, you can easily configure this in our configuration file
>   (applicationHost.config), and here are what entries look like for both
>   a specific address and an address range for both IPv4 and IPV6:

```
<ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">
    <add ipAddress="10.199.199.199" allowed="false" />
    <add ipAddress="12.14.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" allowed="false" />
    <add ipAddress="2001:4898:2a:5:c4ad:9291:22b1:c870" subnetMask="ffff:ffff::" allowed="false" />
</ipSecurity >
```

Comment: Yes. Yes it does. Have a load more reputation on me.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know that!